# working with Unknown number for Round Down

Tags: php

I have a table with a decimal field, which I need to round down.

Here's a data snippet of the table:

```
number
9.5
9.53
7.25
6.9
9.6
8.0
8.3
8.75
9.0
12.25
12.65
11.0
```

If a number is between XXX.0 and XXX.5 the number needs to round down to XXX.0
(eg. 8.3 or 12.25 expecting 8.0 or 12.0)

If the number is between XXX.5 and XXX.0 the number needs to round down to XXX.5
(eg. 9.53 or 9.6 expecting 9.5 or 9.5)

Else the number should stay unchanged
(eg. 8.0 or 11.0)

Here is my question:
How can I define what is in front of the decimal, this can be anything between 0 and 20? I have not found anything similar anywhere...
Is there a way to only look at the value after the decimal?

Here is a sample code snipped, where XXX is the unknown part of the decimal number:

```
if(($number > XXX.0) && ($number < XXX.5))
    { $newNumber = round($number, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); }

elseif(($number > XXX.5) && ($number < XXX.0))
    { $newNumber = round($number, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); }

elseif(($number == XXX.5) || ($number == XXX.0))
    { $newNumber = $number; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`fmod`](http://php.net/fmod) to return the floating point remainder, then do a simple [ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to output your desired result.

```
<?php

$n = array(
8.3, //8.0
12.25, //12.00
9.53, //9.5
9.6 //9.5
);

foreach($n as $i) {
   echo $i .' = '. (fmod($i, 1) > 0.5 
           ? sprintf("%2.f", (float) (int) $i + 0.5) 
           : sprintf("%2.f", (float) (int) $i)) . PHP_EOL; 
}
```

https://eval.in/411076

And in function form;

```
function round_mid($i) {
   return (fmod($i, 1) > 0.5 
             ? sprintf("%2.f", (float) (int) $i + 0.5) 
             : sprintf("%2.f", (float) (int) $i));
}
```

https://eval.in/411080

Comment: Hi @hd this is exactly what I was looking for, I now need to update the database with $n (the array in your script), thus instead of echo'ing the output, how do I now assign the output into an array to use in my UPDATE query?

Comment: @hd How do I update my database?    the new variable is $new[] but how do I use it in my query?

Comment: Depends. What is your query?

Answer (score 0):

just cast $number like this 
`$beforeDecimal = (int)$number;`

Answer (score 0):

`$newNumber = floor($number) + 0.5 * (fmod($number, 1) >= 0.5);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$newNumber = floor($number*2)/2
```